# Load php into div element

Tags: php, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to make a little sidebar widget. I understand this should be done with AJAX, and eventually it will. For now though, and for degrading gracefully purposes, I'd like to keep it functional without javascript.

The task at hand:
(note I am using wordpress)

I have a link which captures the year and month which looks like this.

```
<?php $date = "$year-$month";
$nonce = wp_create_nonce("dynamic_date_loop_nonce"); 
$link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?&action=dynamic_date_loop&my_date='.$date.'&nonce='.$nonce);
echo '<li><a class="date_sidebar" href="'.$link.'">'; ?><?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Then in my functions.php I grab the $date string and explode it into an array like so:

```
$date = $_REQUEST['my_date'];
```

Then, in a separate PHP called loopHandler.php I have a standard loop using the 2 variables from functions.php:

```
<?php
    $split = explode("-",$date);
    $year = $split[0];
    $month = $split[1];

    $args = array( 'year' => $year, 'monthnum' => $month );  

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($loop->have_posts()) {  
           while ($loop->have_posts()){  
                  the_post();  
                  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );  
           }  
    }  

    wp_reset_query();

?>
```

My questions are:

1) How do I get my $date variable from functions.php over to loopHandler.php?

2) Once loopHandler.php has processed the information, how do I echo the loop, or load the file into my desired page/div?

The objective of this widget is when a user clicks on the date it loads posts from that month. Right now I understand if it has to do a page refresh but for the time being, that's fine.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to have a include for that specific div like:

```
<div> <? include ("your.php"); ?> </div>
```

I do have to say that I'm also new to coding so I dont know if this is what you mean.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. If I did that it wouldn't have the updated variables of month and year in the loop.